# what is Z[x] in the sense of a unique factorization domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

The wikipedia page on [unique factorization domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain) gives the following example.
[image]

What does the notation Z[something] mean?

Comment: is Z[x] the same as the set of all ax+b where a and b come from Z ?  or is it more subtle than that?

Comment: No, it is more complicated. Think of fields first, i.e., of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)$. Since this is a vector space of dimension $\phi(n)$ over $\Bbb Q$, we have a basis $(1,\zeta_n,\zeta_n^2,\cdots)$, which can have more than $2$ elements.

Answer (score 2):

Given a ring extension $S\supseteq R$ and an element $\alpha\in S$ one denotes by
$$
R[\alpha]
$$
the smallest subring of $S$ containg $R$ and $\alpha$.

In the above example, $R=\Bbb Z$ and $\alpha=\zeta_n$, a primitive $n$-th root of unity.

The ring $\Bbb Z[\zeta_n]$ is the ring of integers in the cyclotomic field $\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)$.

References form this site:

[Adjoining an element to a ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241862/adjoining-an-element-to-a-ring?rq=1)

[Adjoining to a ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47287/adjoining-to-a-ring?rq=1)